# Apache Ignite - Can writeThrough work with TRANSACTIONAL?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, locking, ignite

I am new to Ignite. Happen to find Ignite as an in-memory DB and it might be a good improvement to our current systems.

Here is my situation:

1, We have an existing huge OLTP system. Which is for online E-Commerce.

2, Right now the app uses Spring Boot, and the database is Postgres (AWS)

3, The app contains thousands of sql: select .. from A inner join B, inner join C …. (usually 5~10 tables join)

4, The app uses select … for update to lock entries and perform update. The retry / timeout is configured in the app for concurrency.

5, The system handles online traffic (100 requests/second) also some backend job update. So the concurrency might happen every second on a single record.

Here is my purpose:

1, Wish to change minimum app code to integrate Ignite;

2, Plan to setup architecture as this: App -> Ignite (Memory DB) -> Postgres (Backup DB). (Reason is that we are new to Ignite, to avoid risk of operation. So still prefer to keep Postgres as backup)

Some questions

Q1. writeThrough is not supported to work with TRANSACTIONAL?

Q2, As we require Transaction/lock (select … for update), I use CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL, but it seems can not autosync to Postgres(Q1). Is there a way to have TRANSACTIONAL and Autosync to PG at the same time? Otherwise it is very troublesome. We need to sync ourselves.

Q3, If we implement dynamic dataSource in app, then we can achieve switch to PG if Ignite is down. But that requires data on PG is same as Ignite. May I ask the advice how to keep data consistency between Postgres and Ignite?

Answer (score 1):

writeThrough is supported with TRANSACTIONAL.

However, Apache Ignite does not have transactional SQL in GA currently, so you will need to use cache API transactions (get/put, etc).

Comment: I c. Thanks. So only get/put is available? Is it fine to use cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * from \"GradeCache\".grade for update")).getAll() ?

Comment: No, SqlFieldsQuery will not work properly. It is not a supported scenario unfortunately. It's not "just" get/put but the whole class of JCache methods such as invoke, getAll, remove, etc, etc.